# How do you get nth-child working in Sass?

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I always struggle getting this to work in Sass and it's difficult finding the way to implement this. I have three elements and I can use first-child and last-child, but I can't select the second element.

```
& svg {
    margin-top: 1vh;
    height: 3vh;
    width: auto;
    &:first-child {
      animation-name: fadeIn;
      animation-duration: 3s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      animation-name: fadeIn;
      animation-duration: 3s;
      animation-delay: 0.75s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    &:last-child {
      animation-name: fadeIn;
      animation-duration: 3s;
      animation-delay: 1.5s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
  }
```

How can I select the second element?

Comment: it depends on your HTML sctructure so show it

Comment: Your sass above looks fine. Seems your html might not be right?

Comment: My bad I posted the HTML structure in an answer below. It's just three svgs listed out inside a div.